# Line Icons / Filled Icons

Tags: icons

When to use line icons and when filled icons ? Is it something related to personal choice or it depends on the visual balance of the screen.

Comment: I would say it is a design choice, depending on the page content, etc. line could suit better than filled (I personally prefer filled). Take a look at the [Spotify icon redesign](https://medium.com/@andrealimjoco/redesigning-the-spotify-icon-suite-63f16853ba00).

Comment: This sounds like an issue for your Visual Design team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's important to consider the visual balance while choosing they type of icons - plus the cognitive load as well. My personal opinion is to use solid icons as they reduce cognitive load and increase interaction speed.

Here's a great study done on this topic:

> Averaged across all 20 icons, hollow icons were selected about 0.1
>   second slower than solid icons, which would seem to support [Johnson’s
>   assertion](https://medium.com/@aub/hollow-icons-a93647e5a44b#.yowaoqwof) that hollow icons require more cognitive effort to recognize
>   than solid icons (if only a very small amount more). However, the
>   picture isn’t yet complete.
>
> https://www.viget.com/articles/are-hollow-icons-really-harder-to-recognize-a-research-study